# How to remove extreme hills grass

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've come to despise the dead look of grass in extreme hills, and noticed that it isn't in as a texture in my resource pack (I don't think) so is there a way to make extreme hills grass look the same as plains grass?

Comment: I'm working on a texturepack right now since I figured out how to solve the issue; I will post the solution soon. Do you want the trees to match the plains biome as well? Or just the grass?

Comment: Both would be nice, and I use faithfulvenom x32 if that changes anything, and thank you so much! @Venoda

Comment: 1.10 I assume, or an earlier version? Shouldn't make a huge difference as long as it's 1.9 or newer if my memory serves me.

Comment: Yep 1.10 @Venoda , and yeah im pretty sure that's right

Comment: Okay; I'm looking at the grass color for FaithfulVenom x32 and it should all be one shade of green (like old Minecraft versions). I have tested it in game and I'm seeing that it is. But for you it's not like that? Here's what I see: http://imgur.com/a/ABW6r

Comment: @Venoda Strange... can you leave a link to where you downlaoded the pack from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44023/discussion-between-david-cole-grammar-police-and-venoda).

Comment: The official download site: http://antvenom.com/downloads/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*What follows is a solution last tested with Minecraft Offical Release version 1.10.2 on 8/16/2016, if it is no longer accurate please alert me and or edit it yourself if I don't respond.*

The simple answer is that texture packs have a file that can control this, if you wish to read the explanation of how I figured this out and get a copy of the file that does the recolor of extreme hills to plains keep reading.

---

Okay after much research here's how it works:

Minecraft uses 2 color swatches located either in the jar file of the game or resourcepack with the path: **\assets\minecraft\textures\colormap\filename.png**

The filenames are **grass.png** for the grass colors (duh) and **foliage.png** for the trees and any other 'leaves' blocks. From what I gather from reading the various wikis and forums about Minecraft, the way the system used to work was the environmental variables of the biome determined what the (X,Y) location on the color swatch would be for the color of the grass/foliage in question. There were certain exceptions to this system such as the infamous "swamp colors" that Optifine offers the setting to disable.

After a certain point, the system was simplified to use a single point/region on the color swatch for each biome and then the game would just blend the biome colors near the borders of different biomes to create a smooth transition. I attempted to use a supposed template for the new system from this [official Minecraft forum link](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/resource-packs/resource-pack-discussion/1255785-biome-palette-template-outdated-working-on-new), but it didn't seem to be accurate anymore.

By examining swatches made by the artist André Jolicoeur for his texture pack [Jolicraft](http://jolicraft.com/) as well as those in the .jar file of the game, I figured out what zones needed to be recolored specifically to affect the Extreme Hills biome. It turns out there are in fact two zones that must be altered, one for lower and one for higher altitudes (Y values). I created an altered swatch based on the Jolicraft one where the blue color is for high altitude and the red is for lower altitude.

[image]

After confirming what the general zones on the swatch were for the extreme hills biome colors I made this (admittedly sloppy, but it doesn't matter since the game only uses certain pixels) swatch to replace **grass.png** based on the vanilla (base game) version.

[image]

*There's the splotchy bit of plains-colored green on the bottom right. If you know what you're doing when making a resourcepack this is the only file you'll need.*

I then created a resourcepack that replaced only the **grass.png** swatch and nothing else. Here are the results:

[image]

*Note how the grass doesn't change color across the previous three color areas.*

As you can see, it totally works! But don't just take my word for it if it interests you. As previously mentioned you can either download that swatch I uploaded and save it as **grass.png** for use in a texture pack or you can [download my properly set up and zipped pack here](http://www.planetminecraft.com/texture_pack/extreme-hills-recolored-as-plains/) (Pending Submission).

Comment: Great work, dude! I love it when people put this kind of effort in.

Comment: No problem! I love questions I can really dig my teeth into like this!

Answer (score 2):

There is a file in Minecraft resources called grass.png, under `texture/colormap` in resource packs, that contains the shading for the grass in each biome. You would need to change the pixels for Extreme Hills to those of Plains using an image editor.

Comment: Could I copy/paste and rename the plains file to the extreme hills one?

Comment: It's all one file, a shaded green triangle. You can find it on Novaskin at https://minecraft.novaskin.me/resourcepacks#default/textures/colormap/grass.png

Comment: Colormap folder does not exist in my texturepack

Comment: @DavidCole-GrammarPolice create one

Comment: @dy I'm still not sure I understand how the triangle works. In the link, it is one solid color however the grass texture has so many different textures. Which color do I use?

Comment: @DavidCole-GrammarPolice Copy it from default pack.

Answer (score 0):

The color of the grass is determined by a function which overrides the texture so you need to change the code, AKA you need a mod to archive that.

Edit:That's not necessary after 1.5 i think

Comment: No, you don't..

Comment: Might have been correct at some point, but my testing shows this is not correct for the current game version (1.10.2).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer is to download [Optifine](http://optifine.net).  After installing and launching Minecraft,

1. Go to the startup screen or ESC menu
2. Go to the "options" menu
3. Press the "video settings" button
4. Find the button allowing to turn biome texture differences on/off.
5. Press that and... Enjoy!
6. If you didn't find the button, turn all graphics settings off (except maybe Fancy graphics and render distance) and return to step 5.

Comment: There is no "Graphics Settings" in optifine, and I cannot find the setting you are talking about

Comment: He means all the settings related to graphics. Examples include turning off all the particle effects, turning off clouds, anything that makes the game 'prettier' generally. However, I'm not quite sure that this fixes your problem.

Comment: After further review of Optifine settings, there is a setting for ***SWAMP COLORS*** on or off, but nothing that affects all biomes. This answer is although attempting to be helpful, not truthful.